# Facebook Like button working on localhost but not on production on Django

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-like

I'm using XFBML to display Like buttons for my Post objects on my Django app. On localhost, the Like buttons work just fine. It posts what I Like to my FB profile just fine. But on production when I click the Like button it briefly displays the number `1` and then the number disappears. No errors in Chrome Dev Tool.

You can see it on production [here](http://www.matilah.com)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you app is not well configured. Here is the answer I got in firebug when clicking and watching the network traffic :

```
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":{"requires_login":false,"success":false,"already_connected":false,"is_admin":false,"show_error":true,"error_info":{"brief":"App ID does not match domain","full":"The app ID specified within the \"fb:app_id\" meta tag is not allowed on this domain. You must setup the Connect Base Domains for your app to be a prefix of http:\/\/www.matilah.com\/20\/."}}}
```

With the interesting parts being

**brief**: App ID does not match domain

**full**: The app ID specified within the "fb:app_id" meta tag is not allowed on this domain. You must setup the Connect Base Domains for your app to be a prefix of http://www.matilah.com/20/

What did you enter in the settings of your app at http://www.facebook.com/developers/

Especially the `Web Site > Site URL` and `Web Site > Site Domain`

It should be `http://www.matilah.com` and `matilah.com`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've set the settings you mentioned. FB says might take several minutes for changes to be saved, so I'll wait. Do I need to Submit the app as well?

Comment: Hmm it's been an hour and still no go. I see the error that you got through Firebug as well. `for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":{"requires_login":false,"success":false,"already_connected":false,"is_admin":false,"show_error":true,"error_info":{"brief":"App ID does not match domain","full":"The app ID specified within the \"fb:app_id\" meta tag is not allowed on this domain. You must setup the Connect Base Domains for your app to be a prefix of http:\/\/www.matilah.com\/20\/."}}}`. I've made sure my appId is correct, and Site URL and Site Domain to the values you wrote. Other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: never mind! it started working just now. took a while. Thanks!

Comment: @rabbid great sometimes Facebook takes a while to propagate on its network the change you make in app settings...